# regex in java string

Tags: java, regex, string

While trying some JAVA coding on the codingbat.com site, I came repeatedly to a Question about the functionality of regular expressions in java strings.
I know there are JAVA methods like matches() or finder() as well as replace() and so on, but this isn't where I wanted to go.

Take a quick look at the example:

```
boolean doubleX(String str) {
  if(str.equals("xx")){
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

I wonder whether I could use regular expressions in the string to add a quantifier, for example

```
                      <----- add regex here 
 if(str.equals("x\[x.*]")){
```

Would you sirs, be so kind, to explain me, how I could use regex in strings? After all I understood, I thought, it would be possible even w/o using the java regex methodes, because the escape signal \ makes them usable even in plain code. Did I got this wrong?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? `String.equals` doesn't support a regular expression, `String.matches` **does**! So you have to use `if (str.matches("x\[x.*]"))` if you want to check your string for a regular expression.

Comment: `Would you sirs`: The SO family does not consist only of "Sirs" :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some methods support regex as input and some is not. In general you can't use regex in plain String, because after all it will be just plain string. But some your or framework's methods can support regex inside with Pattern or other approaches.

Answer (score 2):

Use [String#matches(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29)

```
if (str.matches(regex)) {
    // ...
}
```

This will only find out if there is a match for the regex though.

---

What I suggest is that you specify the quantifier in your regex instead of counting the number of matches, like so:

```
public boolean isX(String str, int count) {
    return str.matches("^x{" + count + "}$");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html?is-external=true) and the [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) class

```
private final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("x\[x.*]");
```

and then

```
Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(str);
if (matcher.find())
    doSomething();
```

Comment: thank you for this approach. i do know this way, but because i'm doing it on codingbat.com, i simply can't import the needed package. br